Can I twist and screw two ground wire into one slot in wall switch
I have an old wall switch with loose buttons to be replaced. After unscrewing, I found out that there are two ground wires in the old wall switch.

and my new wall switch has only one slot for ground wire.

Adding 3rd pic (If this helps)

Should I:
A) Buy a new wall switch that has two ground wire slot.
B) Twist and insert two ground wires into the only one slot.
C) Insert either one ground wire and leave another one open.
D) Other options

Please state your approximate loctaion  (like what country you are in)  because wiring rules vary around the world.

I'm a bit worried by gap between the two boxes - there should probably be some sort of protection over the wires there.

@jasen Hi I am from Malaysia.

What is the switch rated to accept in its wiring terminals?

@ThreePhaseEel hi there are text in : 20A 250V~. Thanks.

The manufacturer should be able to answer whether they designed those terminals to accept more than one wire. Have you asked them? Have you asked local electricians or electrical parts suppliers (or whoever you bought the switch from)? Did it come with any usage instructions, and if so do they mention multiple wires?

@Wilson60 -- that doesn't say anything about what wire(s) the terminals are rated to accept

@ThreePhaseEel ah sorry bro, I have limited knowledge in electrical. :-(

@ThreePhaseEel I uploaded the 3rd pic (front view of the new replacement). It is a button only switch. (Not sure if that info helps)

Never put more than one wire under a screw. Instead:
D) Pigtail. Connect the two wires with a third wire a few inches long using the locally preferred  connectors, and connect that third wire to the switch.

US wiring rules are for USA,

Two wires under one screw increases risk that they come loose.  I'd avoid it anywhere, whether permitted or not. But, granted, for all I know this is standard practice for that design.

Given that a friend of mine just had a wire come loose from a switch -- lots of sparks -- I would hesitate to suggest anything which might increase that risk.

@keshlam Assuming there is no more comment and answer about any other potential risk, I will follow your advice. I will choose the D) Pigtail way. Thank you very much.
